# Loading thousand of data in a listview without loading all the data at the same time

Tags: android, listview

Actually, I need a Android ListView which can load thousands of data, but the problem is that if i will load the data simply in ListView it will short the memory. So I need a dynamic listview which loads the data only which are visible to the user. Is it Possible?

Comment: yes u can bind 10 to 20 data list first time after that in Async task u add  50 to 100 data or notify adapter like recursion

Comment: Please note that listviews only draw cells when they are need to be shown. I'm assuming you're already aware of that. 
Is the issue that you need to load all the model-data into memory when drawing the listview?

Comment: I have to view thousands of data into ListView by scrolling up-down or down-up, but ListView should load only that data which are visible to user, just for optimization.

Comment: My listview contains various fields including images, So if i will load all the data, it will run out of memory for sure. So i need an optimized way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Use a recycler view and provide the image resource as a link. Dynamic loading of images could be done by Picasso (just google it). It would also be great to see an exact example of your data types, that are provided within one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using Recyclerview. Make a list view in this only the displayed data is used or it makes intent only for the displayed part
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Here is a link that may help you - https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Yeah, You are right. RecyclerView is the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

ListView has already had build-in recycle view mechanism. Just don't ignore ViewHolder pattern. Check [example](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView).

You can try RecyclerView if you really need animation.

Answer (score 1):

you can try ListView dynamically Load more . check http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-load-more-data.html